# Attributes not being saved to the database with .build or update_attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I can see all the correct parameters in the post message, but they are not being saved to the database. Here is the controller code:

```
  def create
    @ask = current_user.asks.build(params[:ask])
    @ask.save
  end

def update
    @ask = current_user.asks.find_by_id(params[:id])
    next_step = @ask.check_change(params[:ask])
    if next_step == "ask2"
      @ask.update_attributes(params[:ask])
      ask2
      flash[:notice] = "Description added"
    elsif next_step == "ask3"
      @ask.update_attributes(params[:ask])
      ask3
      flash[:notice] = "Helper and public added"
    elsif next_step == "ask4"
      @ask.update_attributes(params[:ask])
      ask4
      flash[:notice] = "Category added"
    else
      @ask.update_attributes(params[:ask])
      flash[:notice] = "Not sure what to do"
    end
```

And here is the SQL:

```
Started POST "/asks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-16 12:39:22 -0500
Processing by AsksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"n10gHRjvRpu4z40z+jDSTyOdNJrIm
NQdkPgNeS3XM14=", "ask"=>{"description"=>"new ask description is going here"}, "
commit"=>"Add a need"}
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."i
d" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mbegin transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "asks" ("category", "created_at", "date_
done", "date_followed_up", "description", "done", "followed_up", "helper", "publ
ic", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["categ
ory", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 16 Nov 2012 17:39:22 UTC +00:00], ["date_done",
nil], ["date_followed_up", nil], ["description", nil], ["done", false], ["follow
ed_up", false], ["helper", nil], ["public", false], ["updated_at", Fri, 16 Nov 2
012 17:39:22 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 12]]
  ←[1m←[36m (7.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mcommit transaction←[0m
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered asks/_ask2.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_debug.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered asks/create.js.erb (10.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 25.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
```

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong in the controller, but I've tried a number of permutations and can't figure it out.

Comment: Try with  `@ask.save!`, it will generate an exception if the save fails. This way you'll find more easily what is wrong.

Comment: `current_user.asks.find_by_id(params[:id])` maybe return `nil`, change it to `Ask.find(params[:id])`

Comment: tried both of these, no exceptions on the .save! @Kien Thanh, i tried your suggestion, but that didn't work either. Now with that change, I can see the record being retrieved in SQL but the values SQL UPDATE SET transaction are not being populated with the request parameters. Has to be an issue with my Controller or Model methods. Just not sure what yet :-/

Comment: @Baldrick : this will not raise any exception because `update_attributes` calls an implicit `save`. So `save!` will not be effective because there will be no change. @Kien Thanh this is not a good idea because here we need to update a task that belongs to a certain user.

Comment: @MrYoshiji sr, my mistake, i made wrong test in console. maybe he should update model, i don't see any strange.

Comment: The weird thing is your SQL is trying to do an INSERT INTO instead of doing an UPDATE ... Does the create method work fine?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, create method is not working either anymore...

Comment: I think you have a validation that returns a false and stop the create process... Can you post your Ask model please?